# Making and sending a mix double and int array in c

Tags: c, arrays, sockets

I am trying to send a msg from a socket that will be in the form on

```
double,int,int,int,int,...,int
```

N int values
how can i send it?
i have opened a socket but how can i put all those elements in one array that will be sent in:

```
status=sendto(SendSocket,msg,sizeof(double)+N*sizeof(int),
0,(void*)&out_socketaddr,sizeof(out_socketaddr));
```

Where MSG is the memory(array) of all those elements and out_socketaddr is the destination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
uint8_t array [sizeof(this) + sizeof(that) + ...];
uint8_t* ptr = array;

memcpy(ptr, &this, sizeof(this));
ptr+=sizeof(this);
memcpy(ptr, &that, sizeof(that));
ptr+=sizeof(that);
...
```

Avoid making a struct. Although structs will make the code more readable, they also introduce padding, which will be an issue in this case.

Comment: great, i thought it should be something like that, but i tried with woid and it didnt work, ty

Comment: will it make difrrence if it will be of type char?

Comment: @JohnnyF The raw data should be `uint8_t`, it doesn't make any sense to represent it as anything else. The `char` type has implementation-defined signedness, so it shouldn't be used for storing raw data.